# custom command with BrowserStack+WebdriverIO+Travis

Tags: travis-ci, webdriver-io, browserstack

I have a test case for checking forgot password, so I need to read a link from the email. In order to do it I made a custom command in wdio.conf.js

*browser.addCommand('readLastUnseenLink', function async(){
...
}*

It works fine when testing locally on the laptop, it also works well when testing with WebdriverIO Local testing in Browserstack. But, for some reasons, when I push code to Trvais, I got.

*browser.readLastUnseenLink is not a function*

Does anyone had that issue before or maybe there is some trivial solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue, I have one main file and other 3 are merged with main, so functions were added only to the main one and other cached and didn't updated.